# The etymology of 頭{あたま}金{きん}

Tags: etymology

頭金 means "initial deposit". The meaning of first Kanji is "head", the second - "money, gold". How to understand them both - etymology? "Head" + "money" seems not related.

Comment: There's a similar metaphor in English:  The simple girl who over a year ago asked for guidance then took a head first dive into the unknown. - OED, "head first"

Comment: As in English, 頭 sometimes means "initial" or "beginning". For instance, 冒頭 or 頭文字...

Comment: See also [definition #4 of 頭 in Progressive](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/1093/m0u/%E9%A0%AD/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(It is also referred to as "down payment" in US English.)

I believe it is because 頭金 is the **first** deposit of **money** to get a loan.

In Japanese, 頭 can be used to refer to the head or start of something.

For example,

先頭{せんとう} → head of a line or a list

頭{かしら}文字{もじ} → First letter of a word

月{つき}の頭{あたま} → First part of a month

At least this is how I understand it..but I'm starting to wonder if there is a historical reason/practice for why it is called 頭金..I did a quick search and couldn't find anything online.